# Setting process.stdout to a file per node.js core cluster worker

Tags: node.js, multiprocessing, stdout, cluster-computing

I'm trying to use node core's cluster feature.

I would like the `stdout` and `stderr` streams to output to a file, one for each worker id.

Something much like the following:

```
var fs          = require('fs'), 
    env         = process.env,
    workerId    = env.NODE_WORKER_ID || env.NODE_UNIQUE_ID;

process.stdout =  fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/app#' + workerId + '.log', {
    encoding: 'utf8'
});
```

Unfortunately, it does not seem to rewrite process.stdout like this.

Is there a way to achieve this, or should this be done differently? Currently when I run my cluster I am getting all output from all processes in one console, which is extremely messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

```
    //create a new stdout file stream
    var stdoutFS = fs.createWriteStream(stdoutFile, {
        encoding: 'utf8',
        flags   : 'a+'
    });

    //create a new stderr file stream
    var stderrFS = fs.createWriteStream(stderrFile, {
        encoding: 'utf8',
        flags   : 'a+'
    });

    //pipe stdout to a worker file
    var unhookStdout = hookWriteStream(stdout, function(string, encoding, fd) {
        stdoutFS.write(string, encoding || 'utf8');
    });
    console.log('\n\nPrepared new stdout hook to worker file.');

    //pipe stderr to a worker file
    var unhookStderr = hookWriteStream(stderr, function(string, encoding, fd) {
        stderrFS.write(string, encoding || 'utf8');
    });
    console.log('Prepared new stderr hook to worker file.');

    //unhook when things go wrong
    stdoutFS.once('close', function() {
        unhookStdout();
        console.log('Unhooked stdout.');
    });
    stdoutFS.once('error', function(err) {
        unhookStdout();
        console.error('Error: Unhooked stdout due to error %j.', err);
    });
    stderrFS.once('close', function() {
        unhookStderr();
        console.log('Unhooked stderr.');
    });
    stderrFS.once('error', function(err) {
        unhookStderr();
        console.error('Error: Unhooked stderr due to error %j.', err);
    });

});

function hookWriteStream(stream, callback) {
    var oldWrite = stream.write;

    stream.write = (function(write) {
        return function(string, encoding, fd) {
            write.apply(stream, arguments);
            callback(string, encoding, fd);
        };
    })(stream.write);

    return function() {
        stream.write = oldWrite;
    };
}
```

It may not be very elegant, but so far this is the best solution I've found.

Comment: I'm getting 'stdout' not defined (in the hookWriteStream params) ... what do I need to set stdout to?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my idea works to some degree.  As long as most of the logging is done using console.log and not written directly to stdout, you'll be good.

Like I said in the comments below, use a script like this:

```
fs = require 'fs'
{exec} = require 'child_process'

execAndPipe = (execString) ->
    piper = exec execString

    piper.stdout.on 'data', (data) ->
        if data[0...'PROCESS'.length] == 'PROCESS'
            # extract the worker ID and output 
            # to a corresponding file
    piper.stderr.on 'data', (data) ->
        if data[0...'PROCESS'.length] == 'PROCESS'
            # extract the worker ID and output 
            # to a corresponding file


task 'run', 'Run the server', ->
    execAndPipe 'node blah.js'
```

to run your server.  Then just redefine console.log like:

```
console.log = function (d) {
    process.stdout.write('PROCESS' + WORKERID + d + '\n');
};
```

I kinda doubt you'll be able to rebind stdout directly, so this might be amongst your best options.

If you don't want anything to output to the console at ALL, you could rebind console.log like:

```
console.log = function (d) {
    var str = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/app#' + workerId + '.log', {
        encoding: 'utf8'
    });
    process.stdout.pipe(str);
};
```

And forget about the external script.

Comment: I'm afraid this does not work. `process.stdout` is a [Writable Stream](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_stream) and does not have a pipe method according to the docs. I've also tested that this does not write stdout to the given file.

Comment: I don't see the point of your second solution because it does not allow me to write to a separate for file for each worker. In other words, it has to be done within node.

Comment: Hopefully, my updated solution works out for you.  Don't know what kind of build system you use, but it should work with any old thing.

Comment: Away from computer right now, but you could try:

Instead of piping, do:
piper.on('data', function)

Check for a prefix in the data returned in the callback like PROCESS+processnum. Then, rebind console.log to add the prefix in each worker. 

Could potentially work.

Comment: I'm not sure how much of the logging you've got going is using console.log, but hopefully this works out for you.

Comment: If I am going to rewrite my logging functions I might as well make them write directly to a file instead. There is no need for redundant startup scripts or anything. Obviously this is not what I was looking for, also because I'm using more than console.log, such as util.debug. While I appreciate your help I'll leave this question open in hope for a more elegant solution.